# Adding prefixes to certain filenames in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

I need to create a script that will go through and add underscores to all files in multiple directories, ignoring the files that already have prefixes. For example, `_file1, _file2, file3, file4` needs to look like `_file1, _file2, _file3, _file4`

I've got little to no knowledge of Unix scripting, so a simple explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could use one liner like this:

```
find  dir_with_files -regextype posix-extended -type f -regex '^.*\/[^_][^\/]*$' -exec rename -v 's/^(.*\/)([^_][^\/]*)$/$1_$2/' '{}' \;
```

where dir_with_files is upper dir where you search for your files. Then it finds files with names starting not from _, and each of them is renamed.

Before doing any changes you can use rename with params -n -v showing you what operations will take place, without actually executing them.

```
find  dir_with_files -regextype posix-extended -type f -regex '^.*\/[^_][^\/]*$' -exec rename -v -n 's/^(.*\/)([^_][^\/]*)$/$1_$2/' '{}' \;
```

Comment: @michaeljay If my solution works, pleas mark it as correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the best Bash resource out there:

1. Create a [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) which matches all of the relevant files.
2. [Loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Loops_.28while.2C_until_and_for.29) through all of the matching files.

   1. [Remove](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) the underscore from the file name and save the result to a variable.
   2. Prepend an underscore to the variable.
   3. `echo` the original file name followed by the changed file name using proper [quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) to check that they look sane (the quotes will not be printed by `echo` since they are syntax).
   4. Use `mv` instead of `echo` to actually rename the files.

In addition:

- If your `mv` supports `-n`/`--no-clobber`, use it to avoid the possibility of data loss in case you mess up